# Выполнение 2 запросов Mysql в модели Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Есть модель newroom:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class Newroom_model extends CI_Model {

      function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
      }

      function get() {
        $data=array();

        //Первый запрос
        $query=$this->db->query("call GetHomeTypes()");
        $res = $query->result_array();
        for($i=0;$i<count($res);$i++) {
          $data['home_Types'][$i]['Type_ID']=$res[$i]['TypeID'];
          $data['home_Types'][$i]['Type_Name']=$res[$i]['TypeName'];

        }
        //Второй запрос 
        $query2=$this->db->query("call GetRoomTypes()");
        $res1 = $query2->result_array();
        for($i=0;$i<count($res1);$i++) {
        $data['room_Types'][$i]['Type_ID']=$res1[$i]['TypeID'];
        $data['room_Types'][$i]['Type_Name']=$res1[$i]['TypeName'];

        }

        // print_r($data);
        return $data;
}
}
```

Если выполнять один из 2 запросов в модели - все работает,если же вместе - не возвращает ничего.

Answer (score 1):

Что то у вас тут страшное творится)) Если правильно понял вам нужно вытащить из базы зависимость двух таблиц

```
// 
    public function info_user($id)
    {

        $this->db->select('users.*, cities.name AS city');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('cities', 'users.city_id=cities.id', 'inner');

        $this->db->where('users.id', $id);

        $sqlData = $this->db->get();
        return $sqlData->result_array();
    }
```

Тут с помощью join в один массив собирается нужная инфа в данном случаи вся инфа о юзере и имя города

Comment: @igorianru,Какое отношение имеет Ваш ответ к моему вопросу?